# Does VirtualBox Guest Additions relate to Virtual Box Edition? (Can I installed GE on Windows guest and move to Unix host)

Tags: virtualbox

SO my question is if I am running different VirtualBox versions/hosts does it matter if I install Guest Additions from one host and move to another?

IE: Create Windows Guest on Windows Host Installe GE and enable RD then move to Unix Host and run headless with RD